# OpenOffice opens GUI despite --headless argument

Tags: openoffice.org, headless

On RHEL 7.3 I recently installed OpenOffice and was successfully using it (called by a Python script) to convert hundreds of documents between formats. But recently it started trying to bring up the GUI, whether invoked by the script or directly on the command line. Even the following brings up the GUI:

```
soffice --headless --help
```

I've tried all combinations of --headless, --nolockcheck, and --norestore. I don't see any other "soffice" processes running. Is there anything else I should be looking for?

Thanks

Comment: EUS ended for RHEL 7.3 in 2018. Why are you still using it? Can you at least verify whether it still happens with RHEL 7.7?

Comment: This is a corporate environment over which I don't have a lot of control. Everything was working fine until very recently - so I'm hoping there is some obscure process I can just kill and finish the conversion job.

Comment: Opening a document will normally cause a window to open despite the `--headless` argument. Try the solution at https://superuser.com/questions/1135850/how-do-i-run-a-libreoffice-macro-from-the-command-line-without-the-gui.